# HTML Calendar remove selection after first booked class Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this calendar is for date range booking. when user selects first date, jquery is changing td background (makes selection) from first click to cursor current position. Now problem is that selection must stop when meets first booking class. with `.not('.booked')` i did that it ignors booked days but continuing select after anyway. Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //START of date range selection
$('td.days').click(function() {
      if ($("td.firstClick").length == 0) {
  $(this).addClass("firstClick");
 }
});
 
$('td.days').hover(function() {
 if ($("td.firstClick").length == 0) {
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  return;
 }
 $(this).addClass("secondClick");
 var tds = $('td.days');
 var firstClick = $(".firstClick");
 var firstClickIndex = tds.index(firstClick);
 var currentIndex = tds.index(this);
 tds.filter(function() {
  var idx = tds.index(this);
  return idx >= firstClickIndex && idx <= currentIndex;
 }).not('.booked').addClass("selected")
}, function() {
 if ($("td.firstClick").length == 0) {
  $(this).removeClass("selected");
  return;
 }
 $(this).removeClass("secondClick");
 var tds = $('td.days');
 var firstClick = $(".firstClick");
 var firstClickIndex = tds.index(firstClick);
 var currentIndex = tds.index(this);
 tds.filter(function() {
  var idx = tds.index(this);
  return idx >= firstClickIndex && idx <= currentIndex;
 }).removeClass("selected")
});

$('table').on('click', 'td.secondClick:not(.booked)', function() {
 $('.selected').addClass('reserved');
});
});  //END of date range selection
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td {
  width: 14%;
}
table tr td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.firstClick {
  background: green;
}
.selected {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.reserved {
  background: red !important;
}
.secondClick {
  background: green;
}
.booked{
  background:#ffdede;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7"><b>2016</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7"><i>November</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>mon</th>
    <th>tue</th>
    <th>wed</th>
    <th>thu</th>
    <th>fri</th>
    <th>sat</th>
    <th>sun</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="days">1</td>
    <td class="days">2</td>
    <td class="days">3</td>
    <td class="days">4</td>
    <td class="days">5</td>
    <td class="days">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="days">7</td>
    <td class="days">8</td>
    <td class="days">9</td>
    <td class="days">10</td>
    <td class="days">11</td>
    <td class="days">12</td>
    <td class="days">13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="days">14</td>
    <td class="days booked">15</td>
    <td class="days booked">16</td>
    <td class="days booked">17</td>
    <td class="days">18</td>
    <td class="days">19</td>
    <td class="days">20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="days">21</td>
    <td class="days">22</td>
    <td class="days">23</td>
    <td class="days">24</td>
    <td class="days">25</td>
    <td class="days">26</td>
    <td class="days">27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="days">28</td>
    <td class="days">29</td>
    <td class="days">30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So if I understand you right, you want the selection stop when you move your mouse to a date after a cell with `.booked` class and users are only able to select between the dates they have select and first cell which have the `.booked` class unless their second select date is before the first `.booked` class? did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes you did :)
Between selected dates not must be `.booked`. if  `.booked` is between selected dates `.selected` must stop to first `.booked`

Comment: OK, then you have to check if there is a cell with `.booked` class and if so, then check it's _index_ against the `currentIndex` variable. if it was greater than it, then change the `currentIndex` to it's index. I have changed your script a little bit. if you want I can post an answer for it. just let me know if you need it or you can do it yourself :)

Comment: Yes post it please to let me check your answer as correct :)

Comment: OK, So I'll just post the JavaScript part since other parts _html and css_ seems to be OK.

Comment: OK thank you @EhsanT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, as I mentioned in my comment, you have to check if there is a cell in your table with the `.booked` class. If so, then check the `currentIndex` against this cell index, if `currentIndex` was greater than this cell index, then change the `currentIndex` to the first cell index with `.booked` class.

the JavaScript part that needs to be changed `$('td.days').hover(function()` would be like this:

```
$('td.days').hover(function() {
    if ($("td.firstClick").length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass("secondClick");
    var tds = $('td.days');
    var firstClick = $(".firstClick");
    var firstClickIndex = tds.index(firstClick);
    var currentIndex = tds.index(this);
    if ($("td.booked").length > 0) {
        var tdsBooked = $('td.booked');
        tdsBooked = tdsBooked.filter(function() {
            var idx = tds.index(this);
            return idx > firstClickIndex;
        });
        var nextBooked = tdsBooked.first();
        var nextBookedIndex = tds.index(nextBooked);

        if((currentIndex > nextBookedIndex) && (firstClickIndex < nextBookedIndex))
            currentIndex = nextBookedIndex;
    }
    tds.filter(function() {
        var idx = tds.index(this);
        return idx >= firstClickIndex && idx <= currentIndex;
    }).not('.booked').addClass("selected")
}, function() {
    if ($("td.firstClick").length == 0) {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
        return;
    }
    $(this).removeClass("secondClick");
    var tds = $('td.days');
    var firstClick = $(".firstClick");
    var firstClickIndex = tds.index(firstClick);
    var currentIndex = tds.index(this);
    tds.filter(function() {
        var idx = tds.index(this);
        return idx >= firstClickIndex && idx <= currentIndex;
    }).removeClass("selected")
});
```

Comment: I tested and its ok but one thing, now user can not book between bookings :(

Comment: So you mean you may have more than a set of booked cells in your calendar?

Comment: @LaIceKid: I have changed the code in a way that now you can have different sets of `.booked` cells and you can select between them.

Comment: That's exactly what i mean. Works like a charm. Thank you very much for helping me out ;) ;)